# Como esconder uma div quando ela está vazia?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, java-ee

Pessoal tenho uma div para mostrar alertas ao usuário quando um usuário novo é cadastrado com sucesso, porém eu só pretendo mostrar essa mensagem na div, ou seja, a div quando ela não estiver vazia.

Como faço?

Obs.: Vi um exemplo usando thymeleaf porém não funciona, ou seja, o namespace não reconhece no projecto.

Alguém aí para ajudar?

Comment: Podes explicar como essa página é carregada e qual é a lógica para preencher conteúdo nessa div, quando o utilizador é cadastrado?

Comment: Acho que tem uma confusão de tags aí. Java-ee e Java não tem nada haver com o assunto, talvez esteja confundindo tudo como JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como já foi dito por alguns, faça a div ficar inicialmente invisível. Você pode inclusive deixar a mensagem já setada nela:

**CSS:**

```
.divSucesso{ 
  display:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divSucesso" class="divSucesso">Usuário salvo com sucesso</div>
```

Quando o usuário for salvo, faça essa div aparecer, usando o JQuery:

```
$("#divSucesso").show();
```

Se precisar esconder a div novamente, utilize:

```
$("#divSucesso").hide();
```

Caso precise alterar a mensagem exibida, você pode usar JQuery novamente:

```
 $("#divSucesso").html("Nova mensagem");
```

Answer (score 4):

Se entendi sua pergunta, dá para usar somente css para resolver essa questão. É possível definir regras específicas para um elemento quando ele estiver vazio através da pseudo-classe [**`:empty`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:empty):

```css
div {
  border : 2px solid #1abc9c;
  color  : #333;
  padding: 4px;
}

div:empty {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div><!-- DIV VAZIA --></div>
<div>Tenho conteúdo</div>
```

Comment: Amigo @renan tudo bem? Eu quero mostras uma mensagem de **Sucesso** quando um novo usuário é cadastrado, acontece é que essa mensagem será mostrada numa div, então quando estou no formulário de cadastro a div tem que desaparecer e quando salvo um  novo usuário ela tem aparecer com a seguinte mensagem, "Usuário salvo com sucesso".

Comment: Foi o que eu respondi, basta colocar essa mensagem dentro de um `div` com essa regra que coloquei na resposta. Como você não explicou como faz pra essa mensagem aparecer, não tem muito mais o que responder.

Comment: +1 Pelo uso da pseudo-classe

Answer (score 0):

Meio vaga essa pergunta, mas de acordo com a sua descrição do problema:

CSS:

```
 .hide{ 
   display:none;
  }
```

Html:

```
 <div  class="_div"> </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 ...
 if ($("._div").html()==""){
     $("._div").addClass("hide");
 }
```

Se bem que comportamento normal de uma `DIV` é ficar invisível quando sem conteúdo.

Comment: Até aí no HTML entendi, agora no JavaScript não entendi bem, eu tenho uma variável "mensagem" inicialmente ela deve estar vazia e quando salvo um novo registro ela fica com conteúdo, mensagem="Salvo com sucesso" e mostrar a div com essa mensagem @user5978.